# Bottom Share Sheet in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share, material-design

When sharing data in an Android application I have seen multiple applications use a bottom sheet (Google I/O 2015 for ex.) to indicate apps to perform an action rather than the standard dialog which includes apps to handle your intent.

For example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Some title..");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via.."));
```

does not do the trick since the OS version picks the display of the chooser.

Any way to change this code to get the Share Bottom sheet per the material design https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-content[image]

Does anyone know of third party libraries to do just this on older API versions?

I have found https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

but this only lets me create a menu from the bottom sheet. I guess in reality, i can lookup all the apps that can perform the action I am trying to do and manually add Menu Items on top of this library, but i was hoping for something a little simpler since it is not a deal breaking feature.

Comment: "does not do the trick" -- well, it does (more or less) on Android M. The format of the chooser is up to the OS; you don't have control over it yourself. You're welcome to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to roll your own UI. Or, I thought the I|O 2015 app had source available, though perhaps they haven't released it yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare correct, i did notice this was different per device, os and manufacturer.

Answer (score 15):

Here is that same exact bottom sheet on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.

*This may be different on older or modified versions of Android. (i.e. Samsung Devices etc)*

---

**Code**

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this dope website! - https://mikemiller.design/"); // Simple text and URL to share
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
this.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Our BottomSheet implementation has a commons component you can use that lets you specify an intent/filter/etc for the sheet and it will behave fairly similarly to the system version on Lollipop

https://github.com/flipboard/bottomsheet

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of the two answers above: Using the built in Bottom Sheet in M+ and https://github.com/flipboard/bottomsheet for API levels below M.
I prefer the built in Bottom Sheet that Android provides with the share intent because it slides in partially then the user can slide it all the way up.  The third party Bottom Sheet library provides backwards compatibility without having to roll your own so you can drop it in quickly.  However, I prefer the built in.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
  sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content"); 
  sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
  this.startActivity(sendIntent);
}else {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("text/*");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content");
  BottomSheet share = BottomSheet.createShareBottomSheet(MainActivity.this, intent, "Title");
  share.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a Kotlin implementation

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
    type = "text/plain"
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name))
    val shareMessage = "The message you want to sent with this."
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage)
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select app to share with"))
```